Is there a way to check if the user is running in a virtual environment?
I am creating a program that detects if the current machine is a virtual machine (of software like VMware, VirtualBox, etc.) or a host computer for Windows. However, I could not find any code online so I asked ChatGPT and it gave me this script:
import os
if not 'hyper v' in os.popen('systeminfo').read().lower():
 print('Not a virtual machine!')
else:
 print('Is a virtual machine!')

(Might be not 100% correct because my virtual machines are broken)
But I think there is a more efficient and faster way to do it.

"virtual environment" is not the same as "virtual machine". Please edit your question.

there might be a way to determine if your code runs on a virtual machine, but why would you want to? Generally, the whole point of a virtual machine is that it acts exactly like a "real" machine. I've never encountered a use case for this, so I'm wondering what yours is.
